# Problem with validating '<' character in input box

Tags: input, textbox, special-characters, user-input, validation

Whenever I get the .val() of input box with javascript, everything after and including the < character is not included. So if I put "hello<yo"  i receive hello.

So a user typing '<' anywhere in the textbox will either submit a false input he didn't want, or receive the wrong error message

(i.e. if he inputs "<hello", it will say it's blank)

This seems to be fine in javascript alone. But I am getting the val() from javascript and then in ajax i am sending it to a php URl as a query string and validating it there on the php.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT: MY bad i didnt know there was a striptag() function being called in php

Comment: Are you saying the '<' is being submitted as part of the input field?

Comment: Nope, if i do $(#inputid).val() I would not get anything including and after '<' character.

Comment: @Ave how does it look in Web Inspector or a similar tool?

Comment: @Radek S When i type something and inspect it with firebug, the value is still the default it had (not what I just typed)

Comment: I don't seem to be having any problems with this?
http://jsfiddle.net/gailbear/avvyK/1/
Are you experiencing the same problems on the jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmmm... seems to work on jsfiddle. Could it be because im taking the value from a inputbox in a tpl with javascript, sending it as a querystring to a url(php) with ajax

Answer (score 1):

Instead of entering `<` try entering `&lt;`.

Comment: I'm not the one entering input, it's the user. But yeah, thanks, that works for making my question more clear.